# How to get rid of border of UISearchBar?

Tags: swift, xcode, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

### The Problem

I have a UISearchController embedded within a UIView. The searchbar takes up the entire size of the view. However, there's this grey border that I can't figure how to get rid off. I want the search bar to take up the entire size of the view without that pesky grey border.  How can I get rid of it?

[image]

I've tried

```
searchController?.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

But all that does is make the grey border clear (not to mention it makes the searchResultsController of the searchController not show up):
[image]

I want the border to be gone and the search bar take up the entire frame of the UIView.

Comment: Have you added constraints to pin it to the view?

Comment: @paper1111 I don't use constraints. I usually use frame. But if you think constraints would work could you please post an answer w/ the code I need to implement said constraints?

Comment: Do you use Storyboards or XIBs?

Comment: @paper1111 no i do it all programmatically

Answer (score 2):

```
let SEARCH_BAR_SEARCH_FIELD_KEY = "searchField"
let SEARCH_BAR_PLACEHOLDER_TEXT_KEY = "_placeholderLabel.textColor"

func customiseSearchBar() {

    searchBar.isTranslucent = true
    searchBar.backgroundImage =  UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor.yellow, size: CGSize(width: searchBar.frame.width,height: searchBar.frame.height))

    //modify textfield font and color attributes
    let textFieldSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: SEARCH_BAR_SEARCH_FIELD_KEY) as? UITextField
    textFieldSearchBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    textFieldSearchBar?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue" as String, size: 18)
    textFieldSearchBar?.setValue(UIColor.yellow, forKeyPath: SEARCH_BAR_PLACEHOLDER_TEXT_KEY)
}

extension UIImage {

    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

This achieves the UI as per your requirement, let me know if you need more customization on this. This is in swift 3 by the way.